# How do I improve performance of updating Progressbar in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application that needs to provide feedback to the user. I use a WPF window (progress window)  with couple of Progress bars that I tried to update using:

1. Calling a method on the progress window and change the values of program bars
2. Binding the value of progress bars to a ModelView

Both perform the same. 
[Demonstration Application Download][1]

The performance is really slow if I update the progress values every time through the loop. It gets better depending upon how often I update the progress value.

The Demonstration Application gives me the following times:

```
  Interval     Overall Loop Time
  1              23:46 seconds
  10              3:09 seconds
  100              :42 seconds
  1000             :05 seconds
```

I would like to report progress every time through the processing loop. How can that be done?

In my "real" application the processing loop does a lot of processing but updating the progressbar for each unit of work is slow.

Comment: The demonstration download link is:
http://www.starPrinttools.com/PreRelease/WPF_Progressbar.zip

Comment: In case you do not want to download the app, here is the method that I used for updating the progressbar:

Comment: Where's the method? rs

Comment: I was not able to add the method as Stackovrflow complained that too many lines. Sorry. Please download the demo app.

Comment: Can you post it at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and attach the link at your post?

Answer (score 1):

A general approach to designing well behaved applications that need to do processing is that the work should be done on another thread, with periodic messages posted back to the UI to update it on progress.  BackgroundWorker may suit your application - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396